# do while loop with input scanner

Tags: java

I would like to create option with do while were user after inputting correct letter will get out of the loop. I have try to make one but if I put while(type == "Y") it just throws me out of the loop doesn't matter what I press or if I out while(type != "Y") it is going in loop forever, so I am doing somewhere else wrong but I can not figure it out where.

```
public class JavaApplication8 {
static String type;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Press Y to get out of the loop");
        type = scanner.next();
    } while (type == "Y");

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
while (type == "Y");
```

use

```
while (type.equals("Y"));
```

`==` checks if two Strings refer to the same object
`.equals()` checks two objects contain the same data.

Also,it seems that you want to run the loop as long as the user does not enter `Y`.So change it to:

```
while (!type.equals("Y"));
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion Cool Guy. I try equals but it still after I input any key other then "Y" it doesn't go in loop, it throws me out of loop.